# Facebook registration with custom field

Tags: jquery, facebook, forms, api, autocomplete

I have read through the facebook documentation but I am confused on this particular area. I would like to have an option to 'signup via facebook' on my website. By 'signup' I mean facebook will just provide me with the user's information (full name, email, profile picture etc) but the actual user data will be stored in my database.

My problem is that my standard registration form includes a mandatory field called "University name" which is a jQuery autocomplete field with specific values returned from my own database. How would I go about implementing this in a facebook signup script? The custom field option that facebook provides only seems to be a simple text field.

Comment: you may simply ask it from the user if fb doesnt provide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`select` custom field type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) and provide a list of universities:

```
fields=[
    {'name':'name'},
    {'name':'university',
        'type': 'select',
        'options': [{'list': 'of'}, {'university':'names'}]}
]
```